# how does tensorflow assign Ops to run on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm confused about the mechanism that tensorflow uses to assign different Ops to CPUs or GPUs.

1. Taking below pseudo code as an example. Can we say: as long as the `SimpleOp` is
   created within the context of `with tf.device('/gpu:0')`, it will
   surely run on GPU (suppose the GPU implementation of the `SimpleOp`
   is available), **no matter** its input variables (`in_1` and `in_2`) are
   created on CPU or GPU?

   ```
   with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
       out = tf.SimpleOp(in_1, in_2, name='Simple')
   ```
2. I understand by creating a `session` with
       `log_device_placement=True`, tensorflow outputs the device
       placements of all variables/Ops. However, is there a method allowing
       me to check only one Op's device assignment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR; your op created in `with tf.device("/gpu:0")` will always run on GPU. If you specify input to be placed on `cpu`, then they will get placed on CPU. If you omit device specifications for inputs, they will get placed on GPU to be closer to your op. You can use `run_metadata` to get a Python object with all device assignments, and lookup your op there.

Placement is done by misleadingly named [simple_placer.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/beb10ceb086fe94a6b1247b45397aafddd47e05d/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc), and while the comments specify the mechanics, there are still some bugs getting hashed out (ie, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/6615#issuecomment-271051156)), so the best way is to check it in practice.

When you say that variables are created on GPU, there's actually two kinds of placement -- explicit, when you create the relevant op inside the `with tf.device` block, and implicit, outside of such block. Creating ops outside of `with tf.device` is equivalent to creating ops in `with tf.device(None)`  block.

So here's a simple experiment

```
n = 10**6
def inputs_cpu():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        a = tf.ones((n,), name="A")
        b = tf.ones((n,), name="B")
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        c = tf.add(a, b, name="C")
    return c

def inputs_none():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    a = tf.ones((n,), name="A")
    b = tf.ones((n,), name="B")
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        c = tf.add(a, b, name="C")
    return c

def run_and_summarize(target):
    # turn off graph-rewriting optimizations
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0))))
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(target, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    for device in run_metadata.step_stats.dev_stats:
        device_name = device.device
        if not (device_name.endswith("/cpu:0") or device_name.endswith("/gpu:0")):
            continue
        print(device.device)
        for node in device.node_stats:
            print("   ", node.node_name)
```

Now you can do this

```
run_and_summarize(inputs_cpu())
```

That runs with inputs pinned to CPU and you'll see this placement is respected

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
    _SOURCE
    C
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
    _SOURCE
    A
    B
```

On other hand when inputs are not specified

```
run_and_summarize(inputs_none())
```

You can see that now all ops are placed on GPU

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
    _SOURCE
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
    _SOURCE
    A
    B
    C
```

Comment: Superb! I've got it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, recent [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/3f5f9585) clarified the behavior in comments. Basically if you set device explicitly, it'll always be on that device

Comment: I was previously under the impression that TF would implicitly assign ops to GPUs whenever GPUs and suitable kernels for these ops were available. From this description I now understand that TF will only implicitly assign ops to GPUs if other ops that have an input relationship to these ops have been explicitly (e.g. `with tf.device("/gpu:0"):`) first. So if I don't assign any ops to GPUs explicitly, TF will not assign any implicitly either. Is that correct?

Comment: @Drux I quote, "If a TensorFlow operation has both CPU and GPU implementations, by default, the GPU device is prioritized when the operation is assigned. For example, tf.matmul has both CPU and GPU kernels and on a system with devices CPU:0 and GPU:0, the GPU:0 device is selected to run tf.matmul unless you explicitly request to run it on another device." (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#:~:text=If%20a%20TensorFlow%20operation%20has%20both%20CPU%20and%20GPU%20implementations%2C%20by%20default%2C%20the%20GPU%20device%20is%20prioritized%20when%20the%20operation%20is%20assigned.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. In fact, it will fail, if no kernel is available for specified device. But two things should be considered:

   - This can be overridden with [`allow_soft_placement=True`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L214) if session's `config`.
   - `tf.device` context managers can be nested, so if `SimpleOp` wasn't so simple, it might have wrapped some of its parts with `with tf.device("/cpu:0"):`
2. Not that I know of (comments are welcome). You can always `grep` your script output, if you are using *nix, `python script.py | grep your_op_name`. The downside is that you'll need to rerun your script twice: first run with `log_device_placement=True` and `grep`, second run without them.